# Matrix View for Photos from database

Tags: android, delphi, matrix, firemonkey, tlistview

I am wanting to display on Android a grid of photos that are retrieved from a database.  I thought that maybe using ListView with LiveBinding might work but I can't see how it allows multiple records per line.  Anyone have any ideas or can point me in the right direction?  Happy to also look at 3rd party components if diffiicult.

Thanks

Comment: TGridPanelLayout springs to mind.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, seemed quite prosperous at first but it didn't really support scrolling/swiping, it's only good for a fixed number of photos.  I then tried to include a horzscrollbox component which seemed to work ok in testing to a windows machine but didn't work at all testing it on an Android phone.  Looks like its a bit harder than I first imagined.  Is Firemonkey generally pretty good, I seem to be getting compatibility problems even for simple things.

Comment: Use a TFlowLayout inside a scrollbox, and make the TFlowLayout grow as "photos" are added. Yes, if you want the user to be able to "click" the "photos", *and* be able to scroll the scrollbox, you'll need to handle events on the "photos" that prevent clicks if the users intention is to scroll the scrollbox. I've done this myself by creating a control class that contains the images, which overrides MouseDown and MouseMove so that movement can be detected